# fetch API don't return same return of XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fetch-api

I would like convert XMLHttpRequest function to fetch API. But the result is different.

There are some things I have to do wrong, but i don't know what :/

My promise with XMLHttpRequest :

```
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    let formData = new FormData($searchForm);

    if (searchTerm.length) {
      formData.append("search", searchTerm);
    }

    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && request.status === 200) {
        console.log(request);
        resolve(request.responseText);
      }
    };

    request.open($searchForm.method, $searchForm.action, true);
    request.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    request.send(formData);

  });
```

return (what i want) :

> XMLHttpRequest { onreadystatechange:
>   reload/http://localhost:3000/app_dev.php/r…", status: 200, statusText: "OK",
>   responseType: "", response: "{"countMessage":"No product find" }

And my function with **fetch API** :

```
function searchReload() {

  const formData = new FormData($searchForm);
  const url = $searchForm.action;
  const method = $searchForm.method;

  if (searchTerm.length) {
    formData.append('search', searchTerm);
  }

  const header = new Headers();
  header.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

  return fetch(url, {
    method: method,
    header,
    body: formData
  }).then(function (response) {
    return response;
  });

}

searchReload()
  .then(response => {
    return console.log(response);
  });
```

This function return :

> Response { type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/app_dev.php/r…",
>   redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers:
>   Headers, bodyUsed: false }

Anyone can help me ? I don't know what is the problem, and why i can't have **response: "{"countMessage":"No product find" }** to my response :(

Thank you community !

Comment: `bodyUsed: false` means the response body has not be read yet. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/bodyUsed for an example of how to deal with that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `response.json()` to read the body:

```
return fetch(url, {
  method: method,
  header,
  body: formData
}).then(function (response) {
  // perhaps check the status before doing this!
  return response.json();
});
```

Example below of what happens to `bodyUsed` when you read the body

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.bodyUsed);
    var res = response.json();
    console.log(response.bodyUsed);
    return res;
}).then(function(json) {
    console.log(json)
});
```

Comment: I've already test json(), and it return **SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 3 column 1 of the JSON data**

Comment: @StéphaneRICHIN ok, so if you `console.log(response.text())` what do you get?

Comment: @StéphaneRICHIN then your service is not working, but I assure you this is the answer to your question of how to make `fetch` work like your old code

Comment: The HTML returned might be an error page, and might give a clue to what has gone wrong